# Automatically close putty session (server side)

Tags: bash, putty

I have a script in bash, runing multiple putty sessions in my linux vm. For example, i open the connection to run a couple of commands, when it finishes it saves the values, closes the session, opens a new session and runs a couple more.

This script is supposed to run for 60 hours, more or less, so i need to have everythin automated.

My issue is, when the putty session is open, and connected to the device i need, if at some point the device reboots ( dont know why it reboots, it just does), a window in putty appears saying the connection was terminated (obviously). The problem is that the window stays open ulti i press the "ok" button. So my script just stops there until some manual interaction with the putty session.

Is there a way to automatically terminate the putty session if a disconnection happens? the option "Close window on exit" is already set as "Always".

Thank you for your help, if you need some more information just let me know! regards

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make your script to send commands through a terminal utility *(e.g. `ssh`, or whatever protocol you use)*.

Comment: Because i need to have multiple session opened at the same time.  I have 3/4 putty sessions at the same time running, and when all those end, i go the the next spet which open 3/4 more session to perform diferent actions. Is there a way to have thi sbehaviour with the "ssh" command?

Comment: I didn't try myself, but IIRC my colleague bruteforced a SSH password to a device. There was obvious problem of a timeout upon wrong password, and he sidestepped it just by opening a bunch of sessions. So I think the answer to your question is — yes.